How to prevent PDO prepared query to bind parameters with quotes
I have an old script of mine that I had to migrate from mysqli to PDO.
The following works great in the old way, but produces unwanted results in the new because of quotes being added to the query upon execution.
$temp1 = "column1";
$temp2 = "ASC"
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT column1, column2, column3
                      FROM table
                      ORDER BY ? ?");

if ($sql->execute(array($temp1, $temp2))) {} else {}

As a non-professional in programming I would expected the final query take the to variables and include them into the query to produce a query ordered by column1 ascending. Instead the two parameters are in the query but escaped by quotes which obviously removes the ordering of the results.
What would be the proper way to get them into the query without the quotes?

Something similar: How do I set ORDER BY params using prepared PDO statement?.

Placeholders can only be used for data, not for structural parts of the query.

The whole point of prepared statements is to prevent data from becoming code. In this case, you do want data to become code (you're building SQL dynamically, as you're adding column name and sort specification on the fly), so you don't need or want this specific tool.
